# $variables Vs. $vars

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

What is the difference between

```
function mythemes_preprocess_node(&$variables) { ... }
```

and

```
function mythemes_preprocess_node(&$vars) { ... }
```

in drupal 7.
and what is the difference between preprocess and process functions.
thanks.

Comment: You might want to post another question for that extra question you threw in at the end there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no differences. The name of the argument variable is up to the function writer. You can call it $foobar, if you like :)

Comment: thanks. do you know what is the difference between preprocess and process functions.

Answer (score 0):

The name given to the parameters doesn't make any difference, but the name that is usually used is the one reported in the documentation.

As reported in the documentation for [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7), the preprocess functions are invoked before the process functions.